# Changes to text are applied to all parts with that style

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, microsoft-word-2016

I have a Word template that uses several font styles. I have a body style, which I use for my text in the document and occasionally I need to put certain parts in Bold, Italic, ... and everytime I do so, it duplicates this changes to all other parts that use the font style. I need to press Ctrl-Z to undo that action and make it's only applied to the part I want. Is there an option I have turned that's causing this?

I am using Word 2016.

Comment: Is the **Automatically update** check box selected in the style definition (when you right-click the style and then click **Modify**)? If so, clear it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [cnread](https://superuser.com/users/655797/cnread) in [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1198560/changes-to-text-are-applied-to-all-parts-with-that-style#comment1742775_1198560):

> Is the **Automatically update** check box selected in the style definition
>   *(when you right-click the style and then click **Modify**)?*
>
> If so, clear it.